# Seeing Vs On seeing - Gerund

Tags: grammar, gerunds

Can someone explain to me, the difference between "Seeing" and "On seeing"?

Is "Seeing"  a gerund?

On seeing him, he moved faster.
Seeing him, he moved faster.

Are these two sentences both grammatically and semantically perfect?

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of ambiguity between "gerund" and "present participle".  At least some grammarians think that the terms are out-dated.  There are just "-ing words", which might function a little like a noun in some contexts, and a little like an adjective in another.

However, you can parse "[On] seeing him" as a gerund.  It is filling the place of a noun. For example, you could say "On Tuesday".  In the other sentence "Seeing him" is a participle phrase, since you could not use a noun or a noun phrase in that position.

But a participle phrase or a prepositional phrase can both act as a modifier. And these two modifiers have a similar meaning.  (If I had to find a difference, "on seeing him means "at the time of seeing him" and "seeing him" means "as a result of seeing him", but the sense is so close I can't really separate it)

Comment: So, can I interchangeably use them?

Comment: these two modifiers have a similar meaning.